# How to see a whole DataFrame in Jupyter in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I use Jupyter to develop Julia code. How can I show a whole DataFrame with, say, 200 rows. I tried `head(myDataframe, 200)` but only the first 30 rows are shown. If I do it without the `head` I get 30 rows again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested `showall` in [JuliaBox](https://www.juliabox.org) and it works fine.

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A=1:200, B=rand(200))
Out[]:only showing the first 30 rows

showall(df)
Out[]:showing all rows
```

Answer (score 6):

The output of `showall` looks nasty in a HTML capable display like Jupyter or Weave, so instead you can use the LINES environment variable to increase the displayed row count.

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(A = rand(Int, 100), B = rand(Int, 100))

withenv("LINES" => 20) do
    display(df)
end
```

There is also a `COLUMNS` var, see the `displaysize` function help.

AFAICT to disable the limit altogether you need to change the display context which gets a bit messy and is just generally inadvisable, but here it is anyway

```
io = IOBuffer()
ioctx = IOContext(io, :limit => false)
show(ioctx, MIME("text/html"), df)
HTML(String(take!(io)))
```

Comment: I don't know what's nastier: non-html table or using environment variables for communication